# I want a open source(community edition) document management system on Ubuntu which has a web interface

Tags: sharing, version-control

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on a PC and have been trying to make it a server for hosting the source code and storing documents of our small company. We have a need to run a document management system for our binary machine drawings and other documents.

I liked the Gitlab model for source code control that lets me use Ubuntu as server and provides a web interface for Windows users to work on their projects using clients like Source tree etc.

I tried all the links that I get when I searched on the web - OpenKM, DocMGR, Epiware but none works. Is there none that exists and that actually works on Ubuntu (or Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Github, you may want to check the following two solutions

1. [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), provides per project wiki, user access control, works with various version control systems, finally has a big community of developers offering free and non free plugins. [This page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTos#Ubuntu) shows how to install Redmine on various operating systems including Ubuntu.
2. [Gitlab](https://www.gitlab.com/) is a lot more like Github, works only with Git, offers per project wiki, walls, user access control and more. This page contains instructions how to install [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md).

**Both** Redmine and Gitlab are written in Ruby (Ruby on Rails), Redmine is free while Gitlab offers a Community Edition.

Comment: I have already installed Gitlab for source code version control. I want a document control system which works slightly differently. Instead of a project, I want to be able to create a document with a unique document ID, author name and a version and store it in the document repository and be able to share it with other users.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the need correctly, you need to store the assets of the company, such as images, documents, videos etc. which can easily be found later and are properly tagged. If that is the case, then you can try out [ResourceSpace](http://resourcespace.org/) which can help you categorize content and make it easy for you to find it later.

It is a PHP based applications, and using linux tools such as FFmpeg, ExifTool, ImageMagick etc. to assist in categorizing content and generate thumbnails etc. It would also work fine with Windows users as it offers a web based interface.

Comment: This looks like a good option for my requirement. Is it possible for my Ubuntu server to host the service for other Windows users to use it like clients? OK, I just found this link that answers this : http://wiki.resourcespace.org/index.php/Installing_on_Ubuntu_Linux

Comment: Hello Vivek, I installed ResourceSpace on our Ubuntu server. I started the apache service on port 6060. When I point my browser to it (http://server-name:6060) I get this:                       It works!
This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.                                                         So what do I do after this? the installation page says that I should complete the installation from the browser after pointing it at the service...

Comment: Assuming you put it in /var/www/html/resourcespace directory, you have to access it through server-name:6060/resourcespace post which the installation would begin.